# NSWindow memory options

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift, memory-management

When using `NSWindow`s in my projects, I usually specify the `realeaseWhenClosed` option and just reload it as and when needed. I've googled `NSWindow` memory options and can't find anything specific so:

Could someone please explain to me the differences in `NSWindow` memory options i.e. **deferred**, **one shot**, **buffered**, **retained**, **nonretained**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use buffered as documented here [NSBackingStoreType—Buffered Window Drawing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSBackingStoreType) the other two options (Retained and Nonretained) you should never use as stated there also.

> Buffered The window renders all drawing into a display buffer and then
>   flushes it to the screen.
>
> You should use this mode. It supports hardware acceleration, Quartz
>   drawing, and takes advantage of the GPU when possible. It also
>   supports alpha channel drawing, opacity controls, using the
>   compositor.

Available in OS X v10.0 and later.

> The defer argument to initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:
>   specifies whether the NSWindow creates its window device immediately
>   or only when it's moved on screen. Deferring creation of the window
>   device can offer some performance gain for windows that aren't
>   displayed immediately because it reduces the amount of work that needs
>   to be performed up front. Deferring creation of the window device is
>   particularly useful when creation of the NSWindow itself can't be
>   deferred or when an NSWindow is needed for purposes other than
>   displaying content. Submenus with key equivalents, for example, must
>   exist for the key equivalents to work, but may never actually be
>   displayed.
>
> Memory can also be saved by destroying the window device when the
>   window is removed from the screen. The setOneShot: method controls
>   this behavior. One-shot window devices exist only when their NSWindows
>   are on screen. This means that backing stores are also released when
>   an application is hidden, or when a window is miniaturized.

Comment: Thanks. What about deferred and one shot?

Comment: @RASS added the additional info